# Java Password Pattern

Tags: java, regex, passwords, password-checker

The password checker program is supposed to take user input of a username and password and output whether the password is valid or invalid.

I've been trying to use regex for this but am having an issue. The pattern works for all my rules but one, the username rule.
Also, is there a way to change the output from "true" or "false" to something custom?

My code so far:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class validPassword {
    private static Scanner scnr;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Variable Management
        String un, pw, req; // Variable Variable

        System.out.println("Please enter a username: ");
        // ^Need to implement so if it matches the password it's invalid^
          un = input.nextLine(); // Gathers user's username input
        System.out.println("Please enter a password: ");
          pw = input.nextLine(); // Gathers user's password input

        req = "(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}";
        System.out.println(pw.matches(req)); // Can I customize the output?
    }

}
```

I appreciate any help! :)

Comment: You are aware that with your last edit you changed the meaning from "must contain numbers, lowercase letters and uppercase letters" to "must contain numbers and lowercase **or** uppercase letters"? It now is ok to only have on of lowercase and uppercase letters. And was it you who unupvoted my answer? If so, why?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just initially check if it has that sub-sequence.
I would check that initially then check your password rules. 
So something like this (using a regex):

```
// get username and password
if(pw.matches(".*"+Pattern.quote(un)+".*")){
    System.out.println("Password can't have username in it...");
}
// make sure password follows rules...
```

Better would be to use the `contains` method on strings ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))).

```
if (pw.contains(un)) {...}
```

As far as customizing the output of `matches` you can't. You'll need to conditionally branch and do something different.

Comment: I tried my own if statement earlier and it didn't work, I looked back over it and noticed there were a few logical errors.

Answer (score 0):

For the username check you can change the regex to

```
"(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])((?<!" + Pattern.quote(un) + ").(?!" + Pattern.quote(un) + ")){8,}"
```

which means at least 8 arbitrary characters that are not followed or preceded by the username. This is with negative lookbehind and negative lookahead just as you used the positive lookahead for the requirement that the three characterclasses are contained.

And regarding the custom output, just use a ternary expression:

```
System.out.println(pw.matches(req) ? "yehaw" : "buuuuuh")
```